# Change class of another div on hover - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have searched everywhere yet everything seems to skirt around what I am after and I haven't learnt enough to do this myself so sorry if it is out there somewhere or a stupid question.

This is my current structure below:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="select"></li>

    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="noselect"></li>

    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="noselect"></li>

    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="noselect"></li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="noselect"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

​What I want is when a link is hovered, the 'li' that follows has it's class changed to 'select' and all others set to 'noselect'.

I have included a jsfiddle so you can see what I mean. (Found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/swift29/2Ua2a/1/))

Thanks in advance, Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without resorting to javascript. In plain css:

```
nav:hover .select {
    background:#ff0000;
}

nav li:not(.select):hover +  li {
    background:#000;
}
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/9/

I'd probably, however, simplify it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/58gNm/2/ - just keeps the html cleaner.

Comment: After spending some time with everybody's suggestions I did actually use your simplified version, only because I feel a lot more at home with css, however I was not aware you could do this with css so thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use an ease transition with this, I've been trying but its not working, I don't know much about pseudo classes.

Comment: nope - unfortunately, transitions dont work on pseudo classes - it's the bad thing about them. In that case, you'll really need a "true" element: http://jsfiddle.net/58gNm/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').next('li').addClass('select')
           .siblings('li').removeClass('select');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/3/)

You don't have to toggle two classes, just make sure the `select` class has a more specific selector than the `noselect` class, and it will override it.

Comment: Does this work when the mouse goes away? selection seems to be stuck until you point to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/2Ua2a/6/

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('hover', function() { $(this).parent().next('li').toggleClass('select noselect') }); 
});​
```

Comment: Sure is, but if you change the HTML to have the first one selected at page load, like in the question, it pretty much falls apart -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/7/)

Comment: @adeneo, I beg to differ, I think he applied that class for the first element just for demonstration purposes. It clearly mentions 'first one is hovered', you will not have first one hovered when page loaded. You get 'hover' when actually mouse hovers on it.

Comment: @BuddhiP - I don't see where it says "first one is hovered", I do however see where it says "reverts to the one originally selected on mouseleave", and both our answers are wrong there. The closest is probably the buggy CSS solution by JOPL, and I'm not going to change my answer as I think the entire approach is faulty. There should be an active class and a hover class, and switch the hover class on mouseenter/leave, not toggle two classes and expect to keep the original state etc.

Comment: Thankyou, this is definitely the simplest. I do apologise though I did mean to put 'if' in front meaning I did want the first one to be selected when the page loads, but deselected when others were hovered, yet reselected once you stop hovering as it will mark the page you are currently on.

Comment: @adeneo could you possibley do a fiddle of the better option you are talking about?

Comment: @swift29 - afaik, I'm not that good, I can add more code to solve some issues though -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('a').on('hover', function(){
   var $parent = $(this).parent('li');

    $parent.siblings('li.select').removeClass('select').addClass('noselect');
    $parent.next('li').removeClass('noselect').addClass('select');
});​
```

The code is simple. When hovering a link, I run a funcion. First I declare the parent `li` as a variable because it's easier to read and slightly better for performance.

I then target the sibling, which currently have the `.select`-class, and make it unselected. Lastly, I simply add the class to the immediatly following `li`.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/5/